# understanding provability

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I am still confused about provability.

.

.

Let a statement P is, sort-of-says like this.

> P: ( "X is provable" ∧ "P is provable" )

If ( X is provable ∧ P is provable ) is provable →  (P is provable) is provable → P is provable

Hence,

> ( X is provable V P is provable ) ⊢ "P is provable"

IF (P is provable) is provable → P is provable → (X is provable ∧ P is provable) is provable

> "P is provable" ⊢  ( X is provable ∧ P is provable)

Therefore,

> ( X is provable ∧ P is provable ) :⇔ "P is provable"

So,original statement P is sort-of-says like this

> P: "P is provable"

By the Löb's theorem, P is provable.

What the error of this reasoning?

Comment: Why do you think there's an error?

Comment: @JoshKeneda because, X can be anything. If "X is provable" and "P is provable" :⇔ "P is provable", then, P is the statement  sort-of-says, "I am provable". By Lob theorem, P is provable. But X can be anything, so I cannot believe that P is provable always.

Comment: I edited last part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace "X is provable" with $1=1$ to the same effect.  Then you are asking for a statement $P$ which asserts its own provability.  As you say, Löb's theorem says that such a statement is provable, hence is true.  Is this a problem?  We have found a true provable statement.

Comment: X can be anything. For example, let P: "1=0 is provable and P is provable. According previous reasoning, P is provable , therefore, "1=0 is provable " is provable. It makes contradiction.

Comment: @HoCheolSHIN: No, I was saying you could replace $X$ with $\top$ to get that P is provable.  If you replace $X$ with $\bot$ then P is asserting "P is false" and you have the liar paradox.

Comment: Thank you @Ross for reply. Anyway, that's why I posted this question. See the last part of my original post.  Regardless of X, ( X is provable ∧ P is provable ) :⇔ "P is provable" . What's the error of this reasoning?

Comment: @HoCheolSHIN:  the forward direction is fine.  In fact P is provable.  The reverse direction fails if "X is provable" is false.  Your claim "IF (P is provable) is provable → P is provable → (X is provable ∧ P is provable) is provable" is not justified if "X is provable" is false.

Comment: .@Ross, at the first setting, "P: ( "X is provable" ∧ "P is provable" )//   Therefore, P is provable → (X is provable ∧ P is provable) is provable"..........

Comment: @HoCheolSHIN:  but if the antecedent is false, an implication is true.  My issue is that you introduced an equivalence in place of am implication and the reverse direction doesn't work.  The earlier one in that direction had an or, not an and.