# understanding provability and more about Löb's theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory

This question is an additional question for my previous question,one week ago.

Link : [understanding provability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347011/understanding-provability)

Fortunately, some persons kindly commented for my question. However, I think I still be in confusion.

I modified previous question like this.

There are two sentences sort-of-says.

> P: "X is provable" ∧ "Q is provable"
>
> Q: P is provable

(1) for direction ->

> If P is provable  → (X is provable" ∧ "Q is provable) is provable →  (Q is provable) is provable  → Q is provable
>
> P is provable  →  Q is provable,  regardless of X

(2) for direction <-

> IF Q is provable → (P is provable) is provable  → P is provable
>
> Q is provable → P is provable, regardless of X

Therefore,

P is provable <-> Q is provable regardless of X

By this result, can I say one of these?

1) P is equivalent with Q regardless of X

or

2) P is a statement of "P is provable", regardless of X

or

3) P is a statement sort-of-says, "I am provable" regardless of X

Surely, my reasoning has an error. Because Löb's theorem says that the sentence of "I am provable is provable. It means P is always provable regardless of X. It is contradiction.

What is my error?

For one week ago's question, a person commented to me that direction <- has an error. But I cannot understand yet exactly what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work with PA here for simplicity. What I say here is true for ZFC and other systems as well.

Keep in mind that "P is provable" is shorthand for "there exists x such that x codes a proof of P". Now if $PA\vdash$"there exists x such that x codes a proof of P", then also $\mathbb{N}\models$"there exists x such that x codes a proof of P", since $\mathbb{N}\models PA$, so there is some *standard* x coding a proof of P. This x can be translated into a really proof (of finite length) of P in PA, and we can conclude that $PA\vdash P$.

Now let's look at your argument. You assume P, conclude that Q is provable, and from this conclude Q. That is,

$PA + P \vdash$"there exists x such that x codes a proof of Q".

Can we conclude that $PA + P\vdash Q$? Not necessarily! It may be that $\mathbb{N}$ is NOT a model of $PA + P$. In fact, this is the case if $X$ is a statement which is false in $\mathbb{N}$. Then $PA + P\vdash$"there exists x such that x codes a proof of P" means that every model of $PA + P$ (if this theory is even consistent) has an element which codes a "proof" (from the perspective of this model) of P. But if this element is a nonstandard element, then this "proof" won't translate to a real finite proof.

Comment: Thank you! I think you know the answer for my question. Honestly, it is too difficult for me to understand. But anyway, do you mean that "   PA+P  ⊢ (PA⊢Q) doesn't imply automatically PA+P  ⊢ Q "  ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

As you have proven, $P\leftrightarrow Q$, i.e. $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent. By this, $P$ is equivalent to its own provability, i.e. $P$ is either true and provably so, or it is not.

Comment: Thank you @Hagen von Eitzen. How about Löb's theorem? Löb's theorem says that if P is equivalent to its own provability, P is provable by ZFC. But it is contradiction because it means P is always provable regardless of X.

Comment: Hm, reight now I'm confused by Löw's theorem. I'm afraid that the non-constructive *existence* of a proof of $P$ does not give us a proof of $P$. However, in every model of ZFC, there is a proof, hence $P$ is true.

Comment: What is "non-constructive existence of a proof"? However, some says to me that the error of my reasoning is that ZFC doesn't allow self-reference. I don't understand ZFC's self-reference restriction.

Comment: @Hagen: The proof of Löb's theorem is constructive. It shows, given a proof of $\mathrm{Provable}(\ulcorner P\urcorner)\to P$, how to construct a proof of $P$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, so it makes contradiction because it means P is always provable regardless of X.